# Как можно скрыть XML элемент из java класса

Tags: java, android

Можно ли скрыть элемент от XML из Java класса в adnroid studio? Если да, то можете показать как? К примеру: у меня одна XML активность для нескольких java классов и в я бы хотел скрыть таймер, как это сделать? Допустим в css это hidden: none; у элемента.

Comment: `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью метода `view.setVisibility` можно устанавливать видимость View. В качестве параметра можно передать одно из трех значений:

1. View.GONE - убирает Ваш View с экрана. Она становится невидимой и больше не занимает места в макете
2. View.INVISIBLE - View становится невидимой, но по прежнему занимает место в макете.
3. View.VISIBLE - View видима на экране.

Если сравнивать с CSS, то:

- hidden <=> View.INVISIBLE
- none <=> View.GONE.